# Setting maximum date for datepicker

Tags: android, datepicker

```
DatePickerDialog dpd= new DatePickerDialog(this, pDateSetListener, pYear, pMonth, pDay);
DatePickerDialog da = new DatePickerDialog(this, pDateSetListener, pYear, pMonth, pDay);
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
Date newDate = c.getTime();
dpd.getDatePicker().setMinDate(newDate.getTime());
dpd.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(date+(1000*60*60*24*60));
return dpd;
```

Where am i going wrong because this is not working, please help.

Comment: What is `da`? What is `date`? Use `dpd.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(newDate.getTime()+(1000*60*60*24*60));` I would say. And remove unrelevent code.

Comment: it worked for me after i put 1000L instead of 1000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked for me try it

```
 private void handelDate(){
    if(minDate!=null){
        Calendar min= Calendar.getInstance();
        min.setTime(minDate);
        min.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, min.getMinimum(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
        min.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min.getMinimum(Calendar.MINUTE));
        min.set(Calendar.SECOND, min.getMinimum(Calendar.SECOND));
        min.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, min.getMinimum(Calendar.MILLISECOND));

        CalendarView cv = datePicker.getCalendarView(); // should check for null
        long cur = cv.getDate();
        int d = cv.getFirstDayOfWeek();
        try {
            datePicker.setMinDate(min.getTimeInMillis());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        cv.setDate(cur + 1000L*60*60*24*40);
        cv.setFirstDayOfWeek((d + 1) % 7);
        cv.setDate(cur);
        cv.setFirstDayOfWeek(d);
    }
    if(maxDate!=null){
        datePicker.setMaxDate(maxDate.getTime());
    }

}
```